# Include adjusters in order total

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, ecommerce, adjusters

We're building out a Commerce site that needs an "Insurance" option set on an order. Based on the selected option, a percentage of the subtotal should be added to the total amount in the cart.

I've added an adjuster for this, added a field to the order to keep track of which option the customer selects and I can add the adjuster to the order (as in: the type & amount are added to the cart in the backend).

But it seems I can't add that amount to the cart total. In the docs I found this:

> **Included Adjustments**
>
> If you mark the adjustment model’s included attribute as true, the
>   adjustment does not make any changes to the orders value, but simply
>   records an amount that was included in the price of the order.
>
> The only included adjustment we use in the core system at the moment
>   is included taxes.

Is there a way do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post your adjuster class?

Comment: You need to make sure you modify one of the adjustable values on the order? https://craftcommerce.com/docs/adjusters#adjustable-values Your adjuster needs to return the adjustment model as well as modifying tan value on the order like `order.baseDiscount`.